# Database modeling for big data (big set of points X big sets of possible values for each points)?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, database, modelling

I'm building a PostgreSQL database with the intent to host modelisation results for different projects.

Each project has a set of receptors points (**~5000-10000 receptors**) and have many results sets (could be as much as **100 000 results sets** (here called scenarios results)).

Next figure is my actual (simplified) design:
[image]

The problem with this design is that the table **receptor_results** is going to be extremely heavy. For a project with 5000 receptors and 50 000 scenarios, it will generate 250 000 000 rows!

Any suggestion on how I can avoid such thing ?

Comment: 250 m rows is well within Postgres's capabilities. You haven't stated what kind of queries you will want to run, what sort of read/write ratio you might expect, whether there will be many concurrent users, etc. but without knowing any of this, properly indexed, there is no particular reason to fear 250m rows.

Comment: There will be only a few users who will have access to the database, and I don't expect that there will be a heavy load on the database since there is normaly only 3-4 projects running at the same time and the results export will only be made once or twice per project.

Comment: Sounds like the sort of data NetCDF was designed to handle.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, I'm not that much familiar with netcdf format but isnt this format much more oriented for local data stocking? We want to build a database to eventually use the data inside in a mobile cartography app.

Comment: I don't think NetCDF works for mobile.  Your project sounds interesting, could you elaborate on it a bit in your question?

Comment: Little error in my last comment: I meant "web" and not mobile. For the same set of points (i.e, project), we want to have access to all the results generated and allow users to select the specificities of the scenario and visualize the data in a web app.